# adding img in paragraph is causing all its adjacent div slightly moved downward

Tags: html, css

I have set of `div` on my [webpage](http://go.theshashwat.com) with following HTML and CSS.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .div-set {
            margin: 5px 2px;
        }
            .div-set > .widget:nth-child(3n-1) {
                margin: 20px 32px;
            }

        .widget {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
            padding: 0px;
            position: relative;
            display:inline-block;
        }
            .widget h2 {
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 2px 5px;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin: 2px;
                border-top-left-radius: 8px;
                border-top-right-radius: 8px;
            }
            .widget p {
                padding: 3px 10px;
                padding-bottom: 15px;
            }
            .widget > a {
                position:absolute;
                bottom:0px;
                right:0px;
                text-decoration:none;
                background:#dbdbdb;
                color:black;
                padding:2px;
                border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
            }
    </style>

    <div class="div-set">
        <div class="widget">
            <h2>Founder</h2>
            <p>
                <b>Late Shri Brahmdutta Sharma</b> has founded this
                Goshala in 1999 with providing shelter to only three cows and number of cows becomes thirty in just first two months.
            </p>
            <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
        <div class="widget">
            <h2>Founder</h2>
            <p>
                <b>Late Shri Brahmdutta Sharma</b> has founded this
                Goshala in 1999 with providing shelter to only three cows and number of cows becomes thirty in just first two months.
            </p>
            <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
        <div class="widget">
            <h2>Founder</h2>
            <p>
                <b>Late Shri Brahmdutta Sharma</b> has founded this
                Goshala in 1999 with providing shelter to only three cows and number of cows becomes thirty in just first two months.
            </p>
            <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
        <div class="widget">
            <h2>Founder</h2>
            <p>
                <b>Late Shri Brahmdutta Sharma</b> has founded this
                Goshala in 1999 with providing shelter to only three cows and number of cows becomes thirty in just first two months.
            </p>
            <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
        <div class="widget">
            <h2>Founder</h2>
            <p>
                <b>Late Shri Brahmdutta Sharma</b> has founded this
                Goshala in 1999 with providing shelter to only three cows and number of cows becomes thirty in just first two months.
            </p>
            <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
        <div class="widget">
            <h2>Founder</h2>
            <p>
                <img runat="server" src="~/CSS/slide/btns-next-prev.png" style="height:50px; width:100px;" alt="Alternate Text" />
                <b>Late Shri Brahmdutta Sharma</b> has founded this
                Goshala in 1999 with providing shelter to only three cows and number of cows becomes thirty in just first two months.
            </p>
            <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have added an image using `img` tag in last div but as you can see on the [webpage](http://go.theshashwat.com) that all its adjacent divs have slightly moved to the bottom as in image below:

[image]

Changing the `display` property to `inline-table` working in Firefox but not in chrome. I have tried removing `float` property from the image too but no luck.

What thing is causing this unexpected behavior..?? How can I fix that..?

**Please note**: If I add image in all of three `div (.widget)` in a line (a line has three divs) than there is no such issue found. It I add image in two of `div` in a line than remaining one will slightly move to bottom.

[Here is my page](http://go.theshashwat.com)

Comment: If its your website, check again lol, its offline

Comment: @DiederikEEn It is not offline and never have been in recent. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is Causing The Layout to Break?**

Consider the simplified HTML based on the original post:

```
<div class="widget-panel ex1">
    <div class="widget">
        <p>Some text on a line that can wrap around to a second line.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
        <p>Same text.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
        <p>Sane text.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
        <p><img src="http://placehold.it/100x50"> An image and sun text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, a container `div.widget-panel` and four child elements `div.widget`.

The CSS is as follows:

```
.widget-panel {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    width: 410px;
}
.widget {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
.widget p {
    outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

and two additional rules for demonstration purposes:

```
.ex1 .widget {
    vertical-align: baseline;    
}
.ex2 .widget {
    vertical-align: top;    
}
```

and the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/nSWGW/

What is happening here is that the inline blocks are being formatted as a single inline box that is wrapping onto a second line because of the width constraint of the parent element (410px).

Within the parent container, the text elements within the inline-blocks are vertically positioned on a baseline such that the bottom most lines of each paragraph fall on the same (imaginary) horizontal line.

When you add an inline image, you basically increase the height of the inline box which causes the inline-block to move upward since the browser is aligning the bottom lines on the same baseline.

In Example 2, `vertical-align: top` is used, and this tells the browser to align the text elements along the top edge of the inline box.  As a result, the top lines of the text paragraphs are aligned.  However, the top line is also aligned with the top of the inline image, which is correct, but may not be what you want.  You could fix that by using a float.

All of this is correct CSS compliant behavior for formatting inline elements.

Comment: You are welcome, thank you for taking the time to post code and screen shots! this was a good problem to post.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed if you add `vertical-align: middle` to the `.widget` ruleset.

Comment: +1 but would u please tell me what causing this behavior..? I am curious to know

Comment: @harsh, I'm actually not too sure -- you have a lot of funky stuff going on with that layout so it could be a number of things

Comment: funky ..? I thought my HTML to be cleaned :p

Comment: @harsh not *flunky*, just *funky*.  I think it's okay, it's just a little complex

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ruleset(s) to the following. the issue lies with the `display:inline-block;` rule that was on the `.widget{}` I'm not sure why exactly this is causing you an issue.

```
.div-set {
    margin: 5px 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.widget {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```